# How do I convert an ISO 8601 duration to seconds using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt

It seems like this is easy to do in XSLT 2.0 but Microsoft in its infinite wisdom doesn't support XSLT 2.0 in Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: They're on it: http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2007/01/29/xslt-2-0.aspx for two years already! There's bound to be some result soon!

Comment: Hmmm I wonder I can convince my boss to put this off until they get it right. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to do all the parsing and calculation in XSLT.

However, another option would be to extend XSLT with a custom script function in C#:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:myext="urn:myExtension"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl myext">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="myext">

    <![CDATA[

        public int SecondsFromIsoDuration(string isoDuration)
        {
            // parse and convert here;
        }

    ]]>

  </msxsl:script>


  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <root durationInSeconds="{myext:SecondsFromIsoDuration(@duration)}" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The script function will be compiled at runtime to a temporary assembly and then executed. However, be aware to cache your XSLT because every XSLT-compilation will create a new assembly which is only unloaded when your application exits.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know it was so easy to embed C#.

Comment: Yes, it is quite easy. However, some caveats. If you reference external assemblies you might break Mono compatibility, the problem I mentioned with assembly unloading, There are also extension objects, a better suited approach but unfortunately still with worse performance in .NET 3.5 than script.

Answer (score 4):

With XSLT 1.0 you'll have to use substring-before() and substring-after() to split it into individual fields. Then just multiply. No doubt it is possible, although it seems very laborious.

Answer (score 1):

### Converting dayTimeDuration to seconds in pure XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:template name="dayTimeDuration-to-seconds">
    <xsl:param name="duration"/>
    <!-- extract components -->
    <xsl:variable name="sign" select="1 - 2*starts-with($duration, '-')" /> 
    <xsl:variable name="D" select="concat(0, substring-before(substring-after($duration, 'P'), 'D'))" />
    <xsl:variable name="H" select="concat(0, substring-before(substring-after($duration, 'T'), 'H'))" />    
    <xsl:variable name="M">
        <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($duration, 'H')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($duration, 'H'), 'M')" />    
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($duration, 'T'), 'M')" />    
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="S">
        <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($duration, 'M')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($duration, 'M'), 'S')" />    
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains($duration, 'H')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($duration, 'H'), 'S')" />    
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($duration, 'T'), 'S')" />    
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- convert components to seconds -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$sign*(86400*$D + 3600*$H + 60*$M + $S)"/>        
</xsl:template>
```

---

### Test:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <duration>P1DT2H15M30S</duration>
    <duration>PT2H15M30S</duration>
    <duration>-P1DT15M30S</duration>
    <duration>P1DT2H30S</duration>
    <duration>P1DT2H15M</duration>
    <duration>-P1D</duration>
    <duration>PT2H</duration>
    <duration>PT15M</duration>
    <duration>-PT30S</duration>
    <duration>P1DT2H</duration>
    <duration>P1DT30S</duration>
    <duration>-P1DT15M</duration>
    <duration>PT2H15M</duration>
    <duration>PT2H30S</duration>
    <duration>-PT15M30S</duration>
</input>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="duration">
            <seconds duration="{.}">
                <xsl:call-template name="dayTimeDuration-to-seconds">
                    <xsl:with-param name="duration" select="."/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </seconds>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="dayTimeDuration-to-seconds">
    <xsl:param name="duration"/>
    <!-- extract components -->
    <xsl:variable name="sign" select="1 - 2*starts-with($duration, '-')" /> 
    <xsl:variable name="D" select="concat(0, substring-before(substring-after($duration, 'P'), 'D'))" />
    <xsl:variable name="H" select="concat(0, substring-before(substring-after($duration, 'T'), 'H'))" />    
    <xsl:variable name="M">
        <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($duration, 'H')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($duration, 'H'), 'M')" />    
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($duration, 'T'), 'M')" />    
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="S">
        <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($duration, 'M')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($duration, 'M'), 'S')" />    
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains($duration, 'H')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($duration, 'H'), 'S')" />    
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($duration, 'T'), 'S')" />    
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- convert components to seconds -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$sign*(86400*$D + 3600*$H + 60*$M + $S)"/>        
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <seconds duration="P1DT2H15M30S">94530</seconds>
   <seconds duration="PT2H15M30S">8130</seconds>
   <seconds duration="-P1DT15M30S">-87330</seconds>
   <seconds duration="P1DT2H30S">93630</seconds>
   <seconds duration="P1DT2H15M">94500</seconds>
   <seconds duration="-P1D">-86400</seconds>
   <seconds duration="PT2H">7200</seconds>
   <seconds duration="PT15M">900</seconds>
   <seconds duration="-PT30S">-30</seconds>
   <seconds duration="P1DT2H">93600</seconds>
   <seconds duration="P1DT30S">86430</seconds>
   <seconds duration="-P1DT15M">-87300</seconds>
   <seconds duration="PT2H15M">8100</seconds>
   <seconds duration="PT2H30S">7230</seconds>
   <seconds duration="-PT15M30S">-930</seconds>
</output>
```

---

### XSLT 2.0 +

As noted in the comments, in XSLT 2.0 or higher one can do simply:

```
$duration div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S')
```

Answer (score -1):

XSLT 1.0

```
xsl:template name="durationToSeconds">
    <xsl:param name="duration"/>
    <xsl:variable name="days" select="if (contains($duration, 'D')) then number(substring-before(substring-after($duration, 'PT'),'D')) else 0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="hours" select="if (contains($duration, 'H')) then number(substring-before(substring-after($duration, if(contains($duration, 'D'))then 'D' else 'PT'),'H')) else 0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="minutes" select="if (contains($duration, 'M')) then number(substring-before(substring-after($duration, if(contains($duration, 'H'))then 'H' else if (contains($duration, 'D')) then 'D' else 'PT'),'M')) else 0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="seconds" select="if (contains($duration, 'S')) then number(substring-before(substring-after($duration, if(contains($duration, 'M'))then 'M' else if (contains($duration, 'H')) then 'H' else if (contains($duration, 'D')) then 'D' else 'PT'),'S')) else 0"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="($days * 86400) + ($hours * 3600) + ($minutes * 60) + $seconds"/>
</xsl:template>
```

XSLT 3.0

```
<xsl:template name="durationToSeconds">
    <xsl:param name="duration"/>
    <xsl:analyze-string regex="P(?:(\d+)D)?T?(?:(\d+)H)?(?:(\d+)M)?(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)S)?" select="$duration">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:variable name="daySeconds">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="regex-group(1)">
                       <xsl:value-of select="number(regex-group(1)) * 86400"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                       <xsl:value-of select="number(0)"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="hourSeconds">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="regex-group(2)">
                       <xsl:value-of select="number(regex-group(2)) * 3600"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                       <xsl:value-of select="number(0)"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="minuteSeconds">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="regex-group(3)">
                       <xsl:value-of select="number(regex-group(3)) * 60"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                       <xsl:value-of select="number(0)"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="seconds">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="regex-group(4)">
                       <xsl:value-of select="number(regex-group(4))"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                       <xsl:value-of select="number(0)"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$daySeconds + $hourSeconds + $minuteSeconds + $seconds"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your XSLT 1.0 solution cannot work  because there is no `if` expression in XSLT 1.0.  In XSLT 2.0 or higher, the solution is trivial: `$duration div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S')`.

Comment: When I run your "XSLT 1.0" solution with Saxon 10, I get the result of "NaN" for the input of `P1DT1H1M1S`. And neither solution provides for negative input.